# Lyingly: meaning & history of usage

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, contemporary-english

> When President Obama said-- **lyingly**-- that “if you like your plan, you
>   can keep your plan,” his party ultimately paid for it. A reasonably
>   competent Democratic Party, with something like the A.H.C.A. to run
>   against, should be able to make Republicans pay dearly in their turn.

(From a recent [New York Times opinion column](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/06/opinion/house-republicans-go-off-the-cliff.html) by Ross Douthat)

I have a decent vocabulary, but **lyingly** is a word I've not read or heard much, until recently. I'm interested in having a better feel for how this adverb is used and has been used in the past.

I've looked it up in [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lyingly) and don't feel very enlightened, though I understand its basic meaning: **in a deliberately untruthful manner, mendaciously.** i also understand that It is formed by adding -**ly** to the participial adjective, **lying** and that this in turn is derived from the verb, **to lie**.

My question is threefold:

1. Can you give me examples of other current usage and past usage of **lyingly** that might give me insight?
2. How, if at all, has the meaning and usage of **lyingly** changed over time?
3. Do you have any evidence that **lyingly** might be popular right now in the U.S. due to Trump's habits of promulgating "alternative facts"?

Comment: "Lying" can be an adjective ("your lying eyes", eg).  Adding "-ly" to an adjective generally yields the associated adverb.

Comment: @HotLicks, I knew this, but it's a good reminder to put info like this in my question. I mostly wanted to know someone else's anecdotal  perceptions and/or research about whether this adverb is suddenly more common .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/111592?redirectedFrom=lyingly#eid) cites variants of "lyingly" as far back as early translations of the Bible.

> a1382   *Bible (Wycliffite, E.V.) (Douce 369(1)) (1850) Jer. vii. 8*   To steln, to slen, to don auoutrie, to swern **liendely**, to offre to Baalym.

The spelling used in modern English is cited in 1682.

> 1682   *Disc, Addresses or Presentm. to King 20*   Their Popes (who go **lyingly** under the Name of Christ's Vicars).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lyingly&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clyingly%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate that use, at least in books, has not increased in recent times, but in fact, has decreased since the 1980's.

[image]

[Newspapers.com](https://www.newspapers.com/search/#query=lyingly&offset=26) also indicates that the word was most commonly used in print in the 1980's:

[image]

Searching on [news.google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=lyingly&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US735&oq=lyingly&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3j0l2.1055j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=lyingly&tbm=nws) finds few results, so I suspect the term was used by Douthat to add color to her writing, rather than as part of a recent trend in use.

Why the term seemed to have been used more frequently in the 80's is an interesting question.  It could have been a linguistic trend, or the result of one high-profile use that led other writers to use the term.  It could also have been connected to political affairs at the time, though I couldn't find any patterns suggesting that.

Comment: thanks for the well-organized research. This is very helpful, though I can't access the OED entry, because I'm not a subscriber.That's interesting that "lyingly" was used more frequently in the 1980's. – Palizsche 6 mins ago